# jQueryUI datepicker with MVC and knockout js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

Okay I've tried pretty much everything in the other answers I've seen here.

I am using jQueryUI datepicker on my MVC form, which also uses knockout. I want to only display the date, not the time.

Heres my markup:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate.Date, new { @class = "date-picker", id = "StartDate", data_bind = "value: StartDate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate.Date)
    </div>
```

And then in my model I've set the datatype:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

And in the datepicker jquery in document.ready I have the format set:

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

Yet when the page loads, it still displays the time (12:00 AM) along with the date. How can I get rid of this??

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the type of textbox to date.  Using the attributes will only work with the editor not textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this afterwards:

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker("setDate", new Date("@Model.StartDate"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your date value output as `StartDate.ToShortDateString()`